# Conservation of momentum from moving frame

Tags: reference-frames, momentum

A mass M and another mass 2M approach each other at relative velocity 2v (from ground frame v each), and after collision get attached and move together as a single mass 3M. Then looking at the same phenomena from the frame of mass M how is the momentum conserved? (as seen by the observer on M the other mass comes with 2v and then goes to zero velocity after collision).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frame in which mass $M$ is at rest is not an [inertial frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_frame_of_reference), because during the collision it is accelerated with respect to the ground frame (which is an inertial frame). As such, momentum isn't conserved in this frame, as you note. Likewise, Newton's second law doesn't hold in this frame (at least not without introducing a [fictitious force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force)).

Comment: Yes the M frame is not an inertial frame. What I was actually trying to find out is, that on collision some energy will be converted to heat. From the ground frame, it will be the difference in the total energy before and after the collision. This heat can be measured with a thermometer and should show the same temperature from both frames. But ground frame: Mv-2Mv=3Mv', this gives v'=-v/3. Hence energy released will be 3/2(mv^2). But as seen from the M frame, the entire KE of 2M should get converted to heat, i.e., 1/2(2Mv^2), which is not the same as the ground frame.

Comment: @rkn In general mechanical energy, and hence the total energy (mechanical energy plus heat) are not conserved in non-inertial frames. So the mechanical energy conversion to heat calculated in the frame of $M$ is incorrect.

Comment: So is there any way to calculate the heat generated from non-inertial frame on collision? Because we face such cases always on earth.

Comment: You would need to take fictitious forces into account. The total energy will not be constant, but you can use the work-energy theorem to account for the work done by fictitious forces. That said, a lab frame on the surface of Earth is "inertial enough" for most small-scale experiments. In addition, the Coriolis force actually does no work because it is perpendicular to velocity, and unless large distances are involved, the centrifugal force just manifests itself as a constant offset in the gravitational field $\vec g$, so nothing appears to gain/lose energy if you use the apparent $\vec g$.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.